# Break up long string with PHP for outgoing SMS

Tags: php, string, twilio

My client is looking for a way to send a text message to the Twilio PHP script I programmed and then have it rebroadcast to personnel in the field. That's the easy part, simply check to see if the incoming number is authorized, pull the personnel details from MySQL, and distribute.

Here's the tricky part - the people using this may be long winded and their phones allow them to enter more than 160 characters. Assuming that Twilio can receive >160 characters (I know it cannot send >160), I need to break this long message (string) up into chunks that fall under 160 characters.

Here is the script that I came up with to do so, it works great but I would like for it to end on a **complete word**, rather than simply the next character after it is split. Funny side story, when you forget to enter the length at which to split the string, you receive 171 or so one character text messages! :P

```
<?php
$string = "Ulysses, Ulysses - Soaring through all the galaxies. In search of Earth, flying in to the night. Ulysses, Ulysses - Fighting evil and tyranny, with all his power, and with all of his might. Ulysses - no-one else can do the things you do. Ulysses - like a bolt of thunder from the blue. Ulysses - always fighting all the evil forces bringing peace and justice to all.";
$arr = str_split($string, 155); //Factoring in the message count
$num = count($arr); //See how many chunks there are

$i = 1; //Set interval to 1
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    if ($num > 1) {
    echo "($i/$num) $value<br/>"; //(x/x) Message...
    $i++;
} else {
    echo $value; //Message...
}

}
?>
```

Many thanks

**CORRECTION**
Sorry, major oversight on my part - I posted the development script to play with the strings rather than the live script that sends the actual SMS after "the incident." I need to be able to iterate over the chunks to send each out as its own SMS after it is split, as the above will do.. just ending on a complete word. The SMS would be sent in the foreach loop.

Comment: +1 for funny side story... damn - hope you have a handset that allows "Delete All" and not just individual deletion

Comment: Indeed but I blew through like $3.40 in change with Twilio because of that LOL

Comment: Don't they have a way to test your code for free before it "goes live" an oversight by them perhaps?

Comment: I believe so, but since the issue was just how to split up a long string into an array that I could iterate over, I made a script in my playground instead of working on the live file. But rather than copy and paste my working solution (sans ending on complete word), I typed the code over again - forgetting the length at which to split. Murphy's law ;)

Comment: @Daniel, we provide all new customers with $30 to test out the service with.

Comment: @John that's good then! Would that apply to say a design agency who would be using it and testing it for many different clients or projects? Would there be $30 per project or $30 overall?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry that I forgot to mention that. It's great that they provide $30, our system only has light usage and I think that will last us quite a while. Really love the service, does everything I can dream up. :)

Comment: @Daniel it's per account so you can just create multiple accounts to test with. Typically in that case, you'd give one per developer to test with and have a live production one.

Comment: @NightMICU I'm guessing your praise is because we're in the presence of one of the developers ;) - @John The next project we get where we need to make use of that functionality, I'll keep you in mind. Do you support UK networks?

Comment: @Daniel, actually I just like the service and I believe in commending good work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't get why all the over complicated answers when you can just use:

```
$chunks = explode("||||",wordwrap($message,155,"||||",false));
$total = count($chunks);

foreach($chunks as $page => $chunk)
{
    $message = sprintf("(%d/%d) %s",$page+1,$total,$chunk);
}
```

This would produce something like:

> (1/3) Primis facilis apeirian vis ne. Idque ignota est ei. Ut sonet indoctum nam, ius ea illum fabellas. Pri delicata percipitur ad, munere ponderum rationibus.

Online Example: http://codepad.org/DTOpbPIJ *Updated*

Comment: That's basically what I already had - the problem was ending on a COMPLETE word, rather than a fragment.

Comment: This looks like it might be ideal, what is the story behind the |||| in the explode()?

Comment: Basically wordwrap seperates the string by a certain amount of chars, which is what you want, but it does not seperate them into an array, its mainly used for paragraphs to keep within a margin, you would normally use thinks such as "<br />", the reason for the `||||` is that its unique, so when we explode by that we get the split segments in an array, that have the word boundaries and the `||||` removed - You would normally do something lie `-A_secrEtSpLiT((-` to make it more unique.

Answer (score 2):

Try wordwrap: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php

```
<?php

$words = "this is a long sentence that needs splitting";


foreach(explode("\n", wordwrap($words, 10, "\n")) as $s) {
        echo $s . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string first, using a space as a delimiter. Once you have the array, start cycling through it and adding words to a string one by one. Check if the total string length would be over 160 before adding the word onto the string. If so, start a new string. You can do this by storing an array of strings.

```
<?php
$string = "Ulysses, Ulysses - Soaring through all the galaxies. In search of Earth, flying in to the night. Ulysses, Ulysses - Fighting evil and tyranny, with all his power, and with all of his might. Ulysses - no-one else can do the things you do. Ulysses - like a bolt of thunder from the blue. Ulysses - always fighting all the evil forces bringing peace and justice to all."

$arr = explode(' ', $string); // explode by space
$msgs = array(); // array of finished messages

$i = 0; // position within messages array
foreach($arr as $word)
{
    if (strlen($msgs[$i] . $word) <= 155) // this may be 160, im not sure
    {
        $msgs[$i] .= $word;
    }
    else
    {
        $i++;
        $msgs[$i] = $word;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, Scott.. I was actually learning towards it until I saw Robert's code, which was more compact and fit a little bit easier into an already hefty script (going to try and trim that down some, too). I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this (Note: untested, off-the-top-of-my-head, but you get the idea):

```
$string = '<your long message>';
$parts = array();
while (strlen($string) > 155) {
    $part = substr($string, 0, 155);
    $lastSpace = strrpos($part, ' ');

    $parts[] = substr($string, 0, $lastSpace);
    $string = substr($string, $lastSpace);
}
$parts[] = $string;

var_dump($parts);
```